# How to obtain aws lambda arn in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

i'm trying to obtain lambda arn

```
provider:

    ...
    ...
    ...

    parameters:
        register_and_annotate_arn: !GetAtt [RegisterAndAnnotateLambda, Arn]

functions:
    RegisterAndAnnotateLambda:
        name: "lambdaName"
        handler: "handler"
        timeout: 300
```

and this is the error when deploy the serverless

**Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [RegisterAndAnnotateLambda] in the Resources block of the template**

Answer (score 0):

```
provider:

    ...
    ...
    ...

    parameters:
        register_and_annotate_arn: !GetAtt RegisterAndAnnotateLambdaLambdaFunction.Arn

functions:
    RegisterAndAnnotateLambda:
        name: "lambdaName"
        handler: "handler"
        timeout: 300
```